# 4 lines invert grep search in a directory that contains many files

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have many log files in a directory. In those files, there are many lines. Some of these lines contain `ERROR` word.

I am using `grep ERROR abc.*` to get error lines from all the abc1,abc2,abc3,etc files.

Now, there are 4-5 `ERROR` lines that I want to avoid.

So, I am using

```
grep ERROR abc* | grep -v 'str1\| str2'
```

This works fine. But when I insert 1 more string,

```
grep ERROR abc* | grep -v 'str1\| str2\| str3
```

it doesn’t get affected.

I need to avoid 4-5 strings.. can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: What is that string's value? You are expected to give example input/output and/or a minimal, working, repeatable code example.

Comment: Be careful - you are talking about strings "(`insert 1 more string` and `str1` etc.) but you are using grep with regexps, not strings. Learn the difference and use the right tool with the right options for whatever it is you want and use the right terminology when asking for help to do whatever it is you want. When you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input/output, also be precise if you want to search for strings or regexps so we can best help you.

Comment: Do you really need that space after `|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multiple search pattern, i.e. in a way a regex expression. `-E` in grep supports an extended regular expression as you can see from the `man` page below

```
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)

   -E, --extended-regexp
       Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

So you need to use the `-E` flag along with the `-v` invert search

```
grep ERROR abc* | grep -Ev 'str1|str2|str3|str4|str5'
```

An example of the usage for your reference:-

```
$ cat sample.txt
ID    F1    F2    F3    F4      ID    F1    F2    F3    F4
aa aa
bb    1    2    3    4  bb    1    2    3    4
cc    1    2    3    4  cc    1    2    3    4
dd    1    2    3    4  dd    1    2    3    4
xx xx

$ grep -vE "aa|xx|yy|F2|cc|dd" sample.txt
bb    1    2    3    4  bb    1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example should work, but you can also use

```
grep ERROR abc* | grep -e 'str1' -e 'str2' -e 'str3' -v
```